# click on image, remove image and autostart youtube using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

My code gets from youtube all the data needed, generates an image preview and display it. This is my code and working successfully:

```
<?php
```

> `$row['comment'] = preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i", "</br><table style='border:1px solid lightgrey;'><td bgcolor='#EBEBEB' style='vertical-align:top;'><div id='container'><div id='img1'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$1/default.jpg' title='YouTube Video' alt='YouTube Video'/></div><div id='img2'><img src='img/play-button.png'/></div></div></td><td width='370px;' bgcolor='#EBEBEB' style='vertical-align:top;'><font color='#363636'><b>$video_title</b></font><font color='#545454'></br><a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$id}' target='_blank'><font color='#69aa35'><b>Youtube.com</b></font></a> - $video_perigrafh...</font><font color='#949494'>[$view_count views]</font></td></table>", $row['comment']);`

```
?>
```

any idea how I can add a link to the preview image, that it will remove preview image and auto start the youtube video? how can I use jquery for this?

Comment: Well, can you tell us what if anything you've tried so far, and why it hasn't worked?

Comment: really... if you want us to help, at least take the time to format your code so it's readable. YOu've got an ungodly mess there, and NO ONE here has a monitor wide enough to see all of that without having to scroll a few lightyears to the right.

Comment: :-) sorry you are right

Comment: Is it possible to make the table disappear when click on it and make youtube video autostart?

Comment: font tag? Been deprecated for ages.